# How to make Ctrl+B add and remove Bold from selected test in a contenteditable div?

Tags: jquery, html

I am able to edit without problem but Ctrl+B doesn't work. Is there a cross-browser solution?

I didn't want to switch to editable iframe

thanks

Comment: By default it must work in all major browsers when you select text and use ctrl-B and ctrl-I in contentEditable Div. Do u wanna bold when click button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the simplest way, just made a did editable and the ctrl+b works abstracting me of implementing it cross-browser

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#button').click(function() {
            alert($("#editable").html());
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="editable" contenteditable="true" style="width:400px;height:400px;border:1px;border-style:solid;margin:3px;">

</div>
<button id="button">focus</button>
</body>
</html>
```